# Translating a vb.net win forms application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I need to translate an English winforms application I built to Arabic (and potentially other languages as well). I understand on the actual forms it's relatively easy to get the translation working as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289763(v=vs.71).aspx). I just set the language, set the labels etc and move on.

However, what is the best way to translate text that is in the code? For instance, I have a message box that said: "Are you sure you want to quit". Other pieces of code changes the text on labels etc. The quick and dirty way would be to lookup the current language and set the label appropriately, but I'm sure there must be a better way. I guess ideally I would not want to touch the code, but only create a mapping file from English to another language. Would something like that be possible or what is my best option here?

Comment: You should plan for an upgrade and in the next version, use [localized resource files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992030.aspx) for strings. Also you can use [localization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.71).aspx) feature of windows forms designer. Also you need some components like Hijri date picker. You should study more about [localization and globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1021kkz0(v=vs.140).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful